# Basic household energy consumtpion math

Tags: power, watts

This is just for me to understand basic household economics. 
Let's say my electricity provider charges me 1$ for a kWh and let's say I have a device which claims to consume 100W running in my household.

Does this mean, that it will cost me 0.1 dollars per hour?
Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: [Yes.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+dollar+per+kilowatt+hour+x+100+watts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct.  From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilowatt_hour):

> ## Examples
>
> A heater rated at 1000 watts (1 kilowatt), operating for one hour uses one kilowatt hour (equivalent to 3.6 megajoules) of energy.
>
> Using a 60 watt light bulb for one hour consumes 0.06 kilowatt hours of electricity. Using a 60 watt light bulb for one thousand hours consumes 60 kilowatt hours of electricity.